# Including Bullet Physics in Xcode Project for OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, static-linking, bulletphysics

I have been trying to get Bullet Physics to work with my OS X application in Xcode 5.

These are the steps that I have taken so far:

- Downloaded Bullet 2.82 for OS X.
- Downloaded Cmake.
- Used Cmake to build the Xcode project, etc.
- Added the "BULLET_PHYSICS" Xcode project to my project.
- Linked the binaries in Build Phases.

And this warning came up, not allowing me to include the files:

> BULLET_PHYSICS.xcodeproj Update to recommended settings
>
> Project 'BULLET_PHYSICS' overrides the Architectures setting.  This
>   will remove the setting and allow Xcode to automatically select
>   Architectures based on hardware available for the active platform and
>   deployment target.

Also, there are about 94 warnings from the Bullets sources...

I have seen this question: [Bullet physics AppAllBulletDemos missing in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330418/bullet-physics-appallbulletdemos-missing-in-xcode) , but it didn't help my situation.  Please note that I am building for OS X, not iOS.

Am I doing this all wrong?  I need some advice on how to get this to work.